# How to auto "click"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a blackjack game and have a `<button id='standBtn'>Stand</button>`.
I want to get this button "clicked" automatically `if(score(myCards) === 21){/* click Stand button */}`

Comment: Try this: `$('#standBtn').click()`.

Comment: But also.. consider just executing the function that would happen if the user were to click said button. It's a bit weird to "click" the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.click()` function, like this:

```
if(score(myCards) === 21){
    document.getElementById('standBtn').click();
}
```

Or simply,if you use `jquery`

```
if(score(myCards) === 21){
    $('#standBtn').click();
}
```